# Insert command VB does not actually insert data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code which adds a record to the DB. The code executes fine, however when I look in the DB, there is no data added! Any help greatly appreciated:

```vb
Dim Con As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim connstring As String
connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
Con = New SqlConnection(connstring)
Con.Open()
cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into Rota ([Id],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday],[Sunday],[UserID]) Values('" & chosen & "','" & mon & "','" & tues & "','" & wed & "','" & thur & "','" & fri & "','" & sat & "','" & sun & "','" & user & "')", Con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("done")
Con.Close()
```

Comment: Does the query itself work on your database outside the code?

Comment: Yes. If i insert data manually it works fine

Comment: What value does cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() return?  should be of type int

Comment: Maybe there is an open transaction? Or there is an exception not correctly handled? In any case I strongly suggest to use command parameters (like @mon) instead of concatenating the sql string.

Comment: I am sorry, How do you mean? I am not very good with VB. How can i tell?

Comment: +1 on checking what cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returns. Try `Dim rows As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, then `MsgBox(rows.ToString() & " rows affected")`. That should tell you how many rows were affected by the insert.

Comment: It says that 1 row is affected. However it does not actually end up in the DB, if i view it.

Comment: Is your Assignment.mdf part of your project?  If you click it, what is it's Build Action set to?  It may be that each time you run the program, it is copying a blank file over the original.  Also be sure you are looking at the correct file after the insert.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway I have double checked it. Could i be missing something, as in, is it writing to a dataset or soemthing, and not to the actual database???

Comment: If the build action for the Assignment.mdf is not set to Overwrite if Newer, then the file may be overwritten each time you run the program.  That's why I suggested checking that.

Comment: I do not see the option to set it to "Overwrite if Newer" @ChrisDunaway

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the `Copy to Output Directory` setting.  Is it set to `Copy if newer`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes, it is set to Copy if newer!   :(

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I am still getting annoyed by this problem!!!!    Any other ideas???